# Replace consonants in a string with next consonant in alphabet

Tags: java

Here I am trying to input a string and compare the string letters to consonant string letters. When the input letter and consonant matches then output should print next letter of consonant.

```
Example:: input = java
         output = kawa
```

here j and v are consonant so next letter after j is k, likewise after v we have w.

```
BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
System.out.print("Enter any string = ");
String inputString = bf.readLine().toLowerCase();

for(int i=0; i < inputString.length(); i++){
    inputChar = inputString.charAt(i);

    String consonants = "BCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXYZ".toLowerCase();
    for(int j = 0; j < consonants.length(); j++){
        stringChar = consonants.charAt(j);

        if(inputChar == stringChar){
        }  

    }
}
```

Comment: FYI: "*alphabet*" is the entire sequence of *letters* in the appropriate language/country, e.g. A-Z for english languages. So title "replace consonants with next alphabet" should be "replace consonants with next letter", or more specifically "replace consonants with next consonant in the alphabet", since that's what you really want.

Answer (score 3):

*The other two answers produce the right output, but they are not very efficient, so here is my take.*

Your `consonants` should be a constant, and should be simply given as lowercase letters. As a constant, it should be named in uppercase (`CONSONANTS`).

To do a character-for-character replacement, the most efficient way is to get the `char[]` of the original string using [`toCharArray()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray%28%29), the modify the array, and create a new string using [`new String(char[])`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String%28char[]%29).

The easiest way to find the index of a letter in the `CONSONANTS` constant, is to use the [`indexOf()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28int%29) method.

To prevent overflow when adding 1 to the index, use the modulus operator (`%`).

```
private static final String CONSONANTS = "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz";

private static String shiftConsonants(String input) {
    char[] chars = input.toLowerCase().toCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
        int idx = CONSONANTS.indexOf(chars[i]);
        if (idx != -1)
            chars[i] = CONSONANTS.charAt((idx + 1) % CONSONANTS.length());
    }
    return new String(chars);
}
```

Test:

```
System.out.println(shiftConsonants("Java")); // prints: kawa
```

---

Here is an alternate solution that retains the original case.

```
private static final String CONSONANTS = "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz";
private static String shiftConsonants(String input) {
    char[] chars = input.toCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
        char ch = chars[i];
        char lower = Character.toLowerCase(ch);
        int idx = CONSONANTS.indexOf(lower);
        if (idx != -1) {
            char next = CONSONANTS.charAt((idx + 1) % CONSONANTS.length());
            chars[i] = (ch == lower ? next : Character.toUpperCase(next));
        }
    }
    return new String(chars);
}
```

Test:

```
System.out.println(shiftConsonants("Java")); // prints: Kawa
```

---

Follow-up to [comment by @MistahFiggins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37017413/replace-consonants-in-a-string-with-next-consonant-in-alphabet/37017733?noredirect=1#comment61587338_37017733):

> Would casting to int for each character and then modifying the number and casting back be more or less efficient?

My guess was wrong. For the lowercase version (first one above), numeric increment is 36% *faster*.

```
private static String shiftConsonants(String input) {
    char[] chars = input.toLowerCase().toCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
        char ch = chars[i];
        if (ch == 'z')
            chars[i] = 'b';
        else if (ch >= 'b' && ch <= 'y' && ch != 'e' && ch != 'i' && ch != 'o' && ch != 'u') {
            ch = (char)(ch + 1);
            if (ch == 'e' || ch == 'i' || ch == 'o' || ch == 'u')
                ch++;
            chars[i] = ch;
        }
    }
    return new String(chars);
}
```

As you can see, it's optimized to not even consider `a`.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisSavard Input `AbCdEfGhIjKlMnOpQrStUvWxYz` prints `AcDfEgHjIkLmNpOqRsTvUwXyZb`, so it handles `z` ok (using modulus, read the description). --- `StringBuilder` internally uses a `char[]`, but has to reallocate as it grows, and you waste extra allocation and code in the `StringBuilder` itself, so yeah, I'm sure this code is more efficient. Also, it quickly skips processing non-consonants, which you can't do with `StringBuilder`.

Comment: Would casting to int for each character and then modifying the number and casting back be more or less efficient?

Comment: @MistahFiggins Probably less efficient, since you have to do extra work to skip past vowels, but only testing can tell for sure.

Comment: @Andreas I encourage you to benchmark it :). "Extra code" does not have anything to do with efficiency. Specially with Java's JIT. As for the casts, if you look at the internal code of Character.toLowerCase and toUpperCase you'll notice that you are not really gaining anything.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisSavard Ok, benchmarked. A `StringBuilder` implementation that adds one character at a time to the result using `append()` is about 35% slower. --- If you preallocate the internal buffer using `new StringBuilder(int)`, it's only 20% slower. --- Even if you simply copy the entire input into the buffer using `new StringBuilder(String)`, and only call `setCharAt()` for consonants, it is still 5% slower. So yeah, using a `char[]` directly is more efficient than `StringBuilder`. That's because `StringBuilder` also uses a `char[]` internally, so skipping the wrapper object saves a bit.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisSavard As for the answer to Mistah's cast comment, I was referring to the first (lowercase only) version, and I did cloak my answer in "probably" and "only testing can tell".

Comment: @MistahFiggins I was wrong. See 3rd block of updated answer.

Comment: @Andeas Cool - I figured it might be a bit faster (I didn't expect it to be by that much). Also, you might want to look at the `String.toCharArray()` method - but I'm not sure it will be faster because I don't know how it works internally. If anything, all it will do is make the code marginally more readable.

Comment: @MistahFiggins All 3 examples are already using `toCharArray()`. Or am I misunderstanding what you just said?

Comment: @Andreas oh, completely missed that line and how `ch` was assigned - I just didn't read carefully enough, my bad.

Answer (score 1):

```
String consonants = "BCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXYZ".toLowerCase();

String inputString = "java";

String retStr = "";

inputString = inputString.toLowerCase();

for(int i=0; i < inputString.length(); i++)
{
     char inputChar = inputString.charAt(i);

     int indexOfCons = consonants.indexOf(inputChar);

     if (indexOfCons != -1)
     {
           indexOfCons++;

           // if the letter is Z, then go around to B
           if (indexOfCons == consonants.length())
           {
                indexOfCons = 0;
           }
           retStr += consonants.charAt(indexOfCons);
     }
     else
     {
           retStr += inputChar;
     }
}
System.out.println(retStr);
```

Outputs:

> kawa

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class TestIt {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
    {
        List<Character> consonantList = new ArrayList<Character>();
        consonantList.addAll(Arrays.asList('b','c','d','f','g','h','j','k','l','m','n','p','q','r','s','t','v','w','x','y','z'));
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        char[] userInput = bufferedReader.readLine().toLowerCase().toCharArray();
        for(int i=0;i<userInput.length;i++)
        {
            if(consonantList.contains(userInput[i]))
            {
                userInput[i]=consonantList.get((consonantList.indexOf(userInput[i])+1)%21);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(String.valueOf(userInput));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 //declare out side of the loop
 String consonants = "BCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXYZ".toLowerCase();
 //initialize the result
 String op = "";

 for(int i=0; i < inputString.length(); i++){
     inputChar = inputString.charAt(i);
     //find the index of char 
     int index = consonants.indexOf(inputChar);
     //if char 'z' then point to 'b' or to the next char
     op += index==-1 ? inputChar : consonants.charAt(index == consonants.length()-1  ? 0 : index+1);
 }
System.out.println(op);
```